# Duplicating Features based on dates from CSV file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, time

Recently I was able to get some data that has some time elements attached to it. This data is for estimated house values by census tract and replicates itself every month when available. The purpose of this would be do some analysis on housing prices over time and create a time lapse map.

After doing a bit of research it seems like these are two different tables. The time lapse table would need to have separate features for every z_date so it would have to be a many-to-many join? My first attempt at doing this was trying to do a traditional join by right clicking the census tract shapefile and joining it to the csv file that contained all of the data. This did not work in my favor as it only returned the earliest dates from the csv file the correlated with the census tract FIPS code. When I go to join it it comes back with only the earliest record for all of the census tracts.

[image: Table Description]
   
The analysis file would have to be a file that had values across each row for a given period of time (average value by quarter) and then create a percent change by acre column for each year. Is there a better way to do this than grouping in SQL using

> WHERE z_date between 01/01/1996 and 12/31/1996

or

> WHERE z_date like '%1996'

Comment: I have removed the `qgis` tag as you don't mention QGIS at all, and it appears from your screenshot that you are using ArcGIS Desktop.  Asking for a solution in 2 different GIS software would make this too broad (if you want  a solution for both you should ask as separate questions).